# How do I select variables in an R dataframe whose names contain a particular string?

Tags: r, regex

Two examples would be very helpful for me.

How would I select:
1) variables whose names start with b or B (i.e. case-insensitive)
or
2) variables whose names contain a 3

```
df <- data.frame(a1 = factor(c("Hi", "Med", "Hi", "Low"), 
  levels = c("Low", "Med", "Hi"), ordered = TRUE),
  a2 = c("A", "D", "A", "C"), a3 = c(8, 3, 9, 9),
  b1 = c(1, 1, 1, 2), b2 = c( 5, 4, 3,2), b3 = c(3, 4, 3, 4),
  B1 = c(3, 6, 4, 4))
```

Answer (score 50, accepted):

If you just want the variable names:

```
grep("^[Bb]", names(df), value=TRUE)

grep("3", names(df), value=TRUE)
```

If you are wanting to select those columns, then either

```
df[,grep("^[Bb]", names(df), value=TRUE)]
df[,grep("^[Bb]", names(df))]
```

The first uses selecting by name, the second uses selecting by a set of column numbers.

Answer (score 12):

While I like the answer above, I wanted to give a "tidyverse" solution as well. If you are doing a lot of pipes and trying to do several things at once, as I often do, you may like this answer. Also, I find this code more "humanly" readable.

The function `tidyselect::vars_select` will select variables from a character vector in the first argument, which should contain the names of the corresponding data frame, based on a select helper function like `starts_with` or `matches`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyselect)


df <- data.frame(a1 = factor(c("Hi", "Med", "Hi", "Low"), 
                         levels = c("Low", "Med", "Hi"), ordered = TRUE),
             a2 = c("A", "D", "A", "C"), a3 = c(8, 3, 9, 9),
             b1 = c(1, 1, 1, 2), b2 = c( 5, 4, 3,2), b3 = c(3, 4, 3, 4),
             B1 = c(3, 6, 4, 4))

# will select the names starting with a "b" or a "B"
tidyselect::vars_select(names(df), starts_with('b', ignore.case = TRUE)) 

# use select in conjunction with the previous code
df %>%
  select(vars_select(names(df), starts_with('b', ignore.case = TRUE)))

# Alternatively
tidyselect::vars_select(names(df), matches('^[Bb]'))
```

Note that the default for `ignore.case` is `TRUE`, but I put it here to show explicitly, and in case future readers are curious how to adjust the code. The `include` and `exclude` arguments are also very useful. For example, you could use `vars_select(names(df), matches('^[Bb]'), include = 'a1')` if you wanted everything that starts with a "B" or a "b", and you wanted to include "a1" as well.

Comment: Or simply `subset(df, starts_with("b"))` and `subset(df, contains("3"))`. Note that `ignore.case=T` is the default.

Answer (score 7):

I thought it was worth adding that `select_vars` is retired as of `tidyverse` version `1.2.1`. Now, `tidyselect::vars_select()` is likely what you're looking for within the "tidyverse". See the documentation [here](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/tidyselect/versions/0.1.1/topics/vars_rename).