# Creating a dummy variable according to data in a matrix in R

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with 1000 observations belonging to n different countries. Each country has more than 1 observation and the number of observations of each country differ.
I need to create a column with numbers going from (1 to n-1), with each number corresponding to a different country. That is, I am creating a dummy variable and I don't care which country has which number. I just need to create such dummies.
My data are something like this

```
  Region     x
1    be1 71615
4  be211 54288
5  be112 51158
6  it213 69856
8  it221 71412
9  uk222 79537
10 de101 94827
11 de10a 98273
12 dea10 92827
..    ..    ..
```

Each country has its own "code" in the column Region, for instance beXXXX correpsonds to Belgium, ukXXX to the United Kingdom and so on. Hence I suppose I could exploit the initial **2** letters in the column Region to create my dummies. I know from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7562233/how-do-i-select-variables-in-an-r-dataframe-whose-names-contain-a-particular-str) that the command `grep()` could do the job, but I need to have a script which automatically switches from 1 to n-1 whenever the initial letters of the Region change.

The expected output should be like this

```
 Region     x   Dummy
1    be1 71615      1
4  be211 54288      1
5  be112 51158      1
6  it213 69856      2
8  it221 71412      2
9  uk222 79537      3
10 de101 94827      4
11 de10a 98273      4
12 dea10 92827      4
..    ..    ..     ..
```

and in this case 1 corresponds to "be" (Belgium), 2 to "it" (Italy) and so on for the ´n´countries in my sample.

Comment: Please post expected output from your example input...

Comment: You are right.  I posted the expected output. I want to stress that the dataframe is ordered by region (and hence by country), that is I have first all the beXXX observations, then the itXXXX and so on. Maybe this can be exploited to make things simpler.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about creating a factor variable (you can show the underlying integer codes with `as.integer`). We use `regexec` and `regmatches` to extract the letter codes that occur at the beginning of the `Region` variable (ignoring letters that occur later) and turn them into the factor...

```
#  Data with an extra row (row number 11)
df <- read.table( text = "  Region     x
1    be1 71615
4  be211 54288
5  be112 51158
6  it213 69856
8  it221 71412
9  uk222 79537
11  uk222a 79537
10 de101 94827" , h = T , stringsAsFactors = FALSE )

levs <- regmatches( df$Region , regexec( "^[a-z]+" , df$Region ) )

df$Country <- as.integer( factor( levs , levels = unique(levs ) ) )

   Region     x Country
1     be1 71615       1
4   be211 54288       1
5   be112 51158       1
6   it213 69856       2
8   it221 71412       2
9   uk222 79537       3
11 uk222a 79537       3
10  de101 94827       4

unlist( regmatches( df$Region , regexec( "^[a-z]+" , df$Region ) ) )
[1] "be" "be" "be" "it" "it" "uk" "uk" "de"
```

Comment: Hello. Thank you for the insight. However, I still have a problem. I need that the code considers just the INITIAL letters, since I have regional codes as follows:
uk218, uk219, uk21a (it goes from 1 to 9, then siwtches to letters)
The code you provided creates a variable named (uk) and another named (uka). I just need (uk).
About the order, That's not really important, but it can be of use for somebody else. 
Thank you

Comment: You are right. I have >1000 observations and forgot about it. Going to edit the question. Thank you

Comment: @Bob it should work now. You can just use the example data i put in my answer - it would save me from having to re-edit (again!).

Comment: @SimonO101. With your data things are fine. With mine I get this 
Error in regexec("^[a-z]+", code.nuts3$Region) : invalid 'text' argument

I suppose it is my fault yet: can it be due to the fact I have this kind of codes: de111, de11a and dea11 ? Thank you again

Comment: @Bob note the `stringsAsFactors` argument in `read.table`. `Region` should be a string but it is being treated as a factor. Alternatively use `regexec("^[a-z]+", as.character( code.nuts3$Region ) )`

Answer (score 2):

Another option using `gsub` is :

```
gsub('.*(^[a-z]{2}).*','\\1',c('de111', 'de11a','dea11'))
"de" "de" "de"
```

Then you use `factor` and `as.integer` as showed in the previous answer.

Comment: +1 this will be fairly robust, assuming all country codes are two letters.

Comment: May you explain further the usage of '\\1' please? Thank you

Comment: \\1 to take what is grouped between parentheses in the regex pattern.