# In R, how do I select variables from a data frame by string contained in names - either/or

Tags: r, dataframe, variables

I'm aware of how to select variables from a large data.frame based on the column name containing one defined string, as in: ([How do I select variables in an R dataframe whose names contain a particular string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7562233/how-do-i-select-variables-in-an-r-dataframe-whose-names-contain-a-particular-str))

But how do I do this to select columns from the object that contain either one string *or another*?

I'd prefer not to have to split and recombine the df, so that the columns would be kept in their original order.

Here is my sample code, using `grep`, for obtaining variables matching the first string only, which works well:

```
df[grep("top",names(df),fixed=TRUE)]
```

grep won't take logical operators. So how do I select the second set of columns with "base" in the column name?

Comment: `df[grep("top|base", names(df))]`?

Comment: grep won't take logical operators -> actually it does; alternatively use `str_detect` from the `stringr` package, like so: `df[str_detect(names(df), "top|base")]`

Comment: I had tried this, however it returns an df object with all of the rows but no variables in it. I don't think grep like logical operators like |.

Comment: Oh, I've figured it out - using the argument `fixed=TRUE` means that the operator won't work :)

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
df[grep("base",colnames(df))[2]]
```

or, in a somewhat more accurate and less error-prone style:

```
df[,grep("base",colnames(df))[2],drop=FALSE]
```

In both cases, the [2] at the end of the line specifies that you request the second column of `df` which contains the string "base" in its name.