# matching two partial strings in a cell in R

Tags: regex, r, subset

I've read other articles, such as:

[Selecting rows where a column has a string like 'hsa..' (partial string match)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13043928/selecting-rows-where-a-column-has-a-string-like-hsa-partial-string-match)

[How do I select variables in an R dataframe whose names contain a particular string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7562233/how-do-i-select-variables-in-an-r-dataframe-whose-names-contain-a-particular-str)

[Subset data to contain only columns whose names match a condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18587334/subset-data-to-contain-only-columns-whose-names-match-a-condition)

but most of them are simple fix:

1. they only have one string to match
2. they only have one partial string to match

so im here to ask for help.

lets say we have a sample data table like this:

```
sample = data.table('Feb FY2016', 50)
sample = rbind(sample, list('Mar FY2017', 30))
sample = rbind(sample, list('Feb FY2017', 40))
sample = rbind(sample, list('Mar FY2016', 10))
colnames(sample) = c('month', 'unit')
```

how can i subset the data so that my data contains only the rows who's "month" column satisfy following requirements:

1. has year of 2016
2. start with either 'Mar' or 'Feb'

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `grep` returns indices of items it matches, it will return the rows that match the pattern, and can be used for subsetting.

```
sample[grep('^(Feb|Mar).*2016$', sample$month),]

#         month unit
# 1: Feb FY2016   50
# 2: Mar FY2016   10
```

The regex looks for

- the start of the line `^`;
- followed by `Feb` or `Mar` with `(Feb|Mar)`;
- any character `.` repeated 0 to many times `*`;
- `2016` exactly;
- followed by the end of the string `$`.

Comment: Thank you so much! it works! but one question, why cannot i use grepl()? i tried grepl() with same input, the outcome contains only the "Feb" ones.

Comment: `grepl` works exactly the same for me. The only difference is that `grep` returns a vector of the indices of matches (unless `value = TRUE`), and `grepl` returns `TRUE` for matches and `FALSE` for everything else; either works for subsetting.

Comment: hmm for some reason, when i use grepl i'll only retain the feb values... but anyways. thanks very much for the help! :)