# How to select column of dataframe in R when columns have sequential names?

Tags: r

Consider following information pertaining to marks of the students in 4 questions they have answered.

```
Df <- data.frame(matrix(nrow=4,ncol=5)
colnames(Df) <- c("student_id","q_1","q_2","q_3","q_4")
Df$student_id <- c(1:4)
Df$q_1 <- c(3,4,8,10)
Df$q_2 <- c(1:4)
Df$q_3 <- c(7:10)
Df$q_4 <- c(3,5,2,1)
```

I want to take average value of all columns pertaining to question numbers 1 and 3. I create a vector

`q_list <- c("q_1","q_3")`

and

```
q_avg <- rep(NA,2)
```

I want to write a loop which will store average for column `'q_1'` and `'q_3'` in the `q_avg` vector for question numbers in `q_list` vector. I tried with `paste` but couldn't get it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I select variables in an R dataframe whose names contain a particular string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7562233/how-do-i-select-variables-in-an-r-dataframe-whose-names-contain-a-particular-str)

Comment: It is useful, but not exactly relevant. Thanks.

Comment: I'd suggest you edit your question then. The title of your question says nothing about column averages. Kindly edit it.

Comment: It is not about column averages, but selecting a specific set of columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We  can use `colMeans` after selecting the columns from 'q_list'

```
q_avg <- colMeans(Df[q_list], na.rm = TRUE)
```